# "parent.lock" for firefox profile when running selenium maven plugin

Tags: maven, firefox, selenium, integration-testing, selenium-server

When my integration tests are run with selenium plugin for maven

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>  
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start-server</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <background>true</background>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop-server</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

the following message is received:

`Lock file still present! C:\Users\ADM\AppData\Local\Temp\customProfileDirbb53fd86ecaf4236bf538b7a1171814b\parent.lock`

If I delete parent.lock file immediately after the firefox profile is created the tests are working properly.
Does anyone know how to avoid creation of parent.lock file? or any other solution

I'm using selenium 2.33.0

the whole exception is

```
ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox refused shutdown while preparing a profile
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:367)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.populateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:412)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxLauncher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxLauncher.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:381)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:810)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:407)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:151)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher$FileLockRemainedException: Lock file still present! C:\Users\ADM\AppData\Local\Temp\customProfileDirbb53fd86ecaf4236bf538b7a1171814b\parent.lock
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFileLockToGoAway(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:318)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:365)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: I know this post is a bit old, but have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

please ensure the following has been configured correctly
http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/

Comment: I have also tried with custom FF profile, but it does not work. Still firefox profile is created with parent.lock file inside.